# Unable to parse CSV generated with PowerShell

Tags: python, parsing, powershell, csv

Something weird is going on so I'm going to paste my `real` code along with the PowerShell script (which is probably bad but hey...)

```
import-module hyper-v

$vms = get-vm | select name
$allvms = @()

function getRAM
{
 param([string]$vmname )
 $ram = get-vm -name $vmname | select -ExpandProperty memorystartup
 return $ram
}

function getState
{
 param([string]$vmname )
 $state = get-vm -name $vmname | select -ExpandProperty state
 return $state
}

function getUptime
{
 param([string]$vmname )
 $uptime = get-vm -name $vmname | select -ExpandProperty uptime
 return $uptime
}

function getCPUS
{
 param([string]$vmname )
 $cpus = get-vmprocessor -vmname $vmname | select -ExpandProperty count
 return $cpus
}

foreach ($vm in $vms)
    {
    $tempvm = New-Object PSObject
    Add-Member -InputObject $tempvm -MemberType NoteProperty -Name cpus -Value ""
    Add-Member -InputObject $tempvm -MemberType NoteProperty -Name state -Value ""
    Add-Member -InputObject $tempvm -MemberType NoteProperty -Name name -Value $vm.name
    Add-Member -InputObject $tempvm -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ram -Value ""
    Add-Member -InputObject $tempvm -MemberType NoteProperty -Name uptime -Value ""

    $tempvm.ram = getRAM($vm.name)
    $tempvm.state = getState($vm.name)
    $tempvm.cpus = getCPUS($vm.name)
    $tempvm.uptime = getUptime($vm.name)

    $allvms += $tempvm
    }

$allvms | export-csv c:/users/my_username/appdata/local/temp/vmi.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Running this from an **elevated** PowerShell creates the CSV file which can be parsed with this Python code.

```
def _parseCSV(self):
        pwd = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(tempfile.gettempdir())
        print 'currently in dir', os.getcwd()
        try:
            csvfile = open('vmi.csv', 'r')

            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            print type(reader), reader
            for row in reader:
                    print row
            os.chdir(pwd)
            print 'currently in dir', pwd
        except Exception as ex:
            raise ex
        finally:
            csvfile.close()
```

Running it using regular PowerShell produces an empty file, probably Hyper-V module's fault.

An ideal scenario is that my Python code executes the above PowerShell script which writes to a CSV later parsed by the same Python script...except it's tricky to run PowerShell as Administrator from Python, so I'm using this

```
    def _runPowershell(self):
        sp.Popen([r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe',
                                 '-ExecutionPolicy',
                                 'Unrestricted',
                                 'Start-Process',
                                 'powershell',
                                 '-WindowStyle Hidden',
                                 '-verb',
                                 'runas',
                                 '-argumentlist',
                                 '"-file '+self.PSPath+'"'])
    #self.PSPath is c:/users/my_username/appdata/local/temp/vmi.ps1
```

The CSV file produced by this monstrosity can't be parsed by my Python script.

CSV output

```
"cpus","state","name","ram","uptime"
"1","Running","vm1","268435456","00:35:46"
"2","Off","vm2","536870912","00:00:00"
```

Comment: For PowerShell to be related to this question I would be curious if the first line in the file is your header or a type line. Regardless does your CSV look correct?

Comment: Could you change `print str(ex)` to `raise ex` and include the traceback?

Comment: Are you sure those lines are not being executed?. Just because it is not printing what you expect does not mean they're not being executed. Use a debugger or some print statements to make sure those lines are not being executed.

Comment: What does `csv.reader` return on the file? Is the `vmi.csv` file in one of those directories?

Comment: Thank you guys for your interest, I've updated my question with answers to your questions.

Comment: What command are you using to generate the CSV file in Powershell? *Export-CSV* does not by default generate a valid CSV file because the first line of the file contains TYPE information. This could be messing with your script. Try `Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation`. Edit: too slow, this has already been answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works just fine, but PowerShell needed some time to actually close (save) the file. In order to solve this problem, I added a 1 second pause (`time.sleep(1)`) to the `_parseCSV()` function.